# Webpage content disappear

Tags: android, html

I am trying to get the content of this webpage: http://www.tisseo.fr/calculateur?o_p=saint+sernin&dpt=&dac=0&destination_class_filter=&d_p=saint+michel&apt=&arrival_class_filter=&dy=2012-10-11&sh=02&sm=15&tm=17451448556060676&op=%3E%3E+Rechercher

You can see in the source code that there is a element called "row_1"...

However when I do this in my code:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

while((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(nextLine.trim());
    Log.i("content", ""+nextLine.trim());
}
```

Only the beginning and the end of the web page is displayed! And the element I would like to get is not there... But why? I don't understand.

Any idea how to get the content of "row_1"?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You musn't trying parse this webpage.
This page could change without warning.

And if you request the website too heavily you can be banished and your Android application will stop working.

Instead use opendata Tisséo API : https://data.toulouse-metropole.fr/explore/dataset/api-temps-reel-tisseo/

The Journey Planner isn't available for now, but it will be.
(I am working at Tisséo)

**EDIT : since October 2014**

The Journey Planner is now available through Tisséo API

Comment: And it is available since yesterday. See the `journey` method of the new v1 API.